# Half images are shown/added results per page

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a javascript/ajax based search system which calls a file and get json data

> Sample JSON Data

```
{"id":["33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","73"],"user_id":["16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","17"],"name":["Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Ram Bachan","Amar Nath"],"date":["2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21"],"outlet":["Rani Ka Bagh 1","Rani Ka Bagh 2","Rani Ka Bagh 3","Rani Ka Bagh 4","Rani Ka Bagh 5","Rani Ka Bagh 6","Rani Ka Bagh 7","Rani Ka Bagh 8","Hide Market 1"],"approved":["P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P"],"fileName":["409160.jpg","424831.jpg","785371.jpg","27401.jpg","527450.jpg","759700.jpg","540742.jpg","280322.jpg","959879.jpg"],"resultsCount":248,"currentPage":1,"lastPage":28}
```

Above JSON data contain many informaiton and name of images

I am simply parsing json data and adding images in the div

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData['id'].length; i++) {
    console.log(i, jsonData['fileName'][i]);
    var imgName = jsonData['fileName'][i].split(",");
    img[i].innerHTML = "<div><img src='/user_data/" + jsonData["user_id"][i] + "/" + imgName[0] + "' class='image' /></div>";
}
```

What happening is First image is added & displayed next skips third added and displayed next skips so on.

If total search results per page is 10. Only 5 images is displayed

I tried using debugger to find WTH is going on and i found something weird don't no what exactly is happening.

When loop runs and image is added `img` variable sets to

[image]

On next iteration when image is not added `img` variable is set to

[image]

I have crossed checked all images exist and are loaded properly. Network tab in chrome shows all images are requested and there status is 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the elements by `className='image'`, then you are keeping the same class on the `<img>` tag in the `div`. The selector variable gets changed and newly appended '` also gets selected.
This is why loop is not working as expected.

Use either `document.querySelectorAll('div.image');` or put a different class on `img` tags being appended.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj4dtehh/). I have tried with 4 divs, but it seems to work.